extracting a few words from a sentence in a cell, separated by comma, based on a list of words I want from google sheet
I have a document full of sentences and a list of words that I want to extract from them. I want to remove the rest of the words. How can I do that?



words I want
sentence
desired outcome




apple
the bear ate an apple up the tree.
bear,apple,up


bear
i like potato



up
you hate apple pie?
apple



i went, up the apple tree
up,tree




Here is the link to a sample doc.
I can remove the punctuations, and change the sentence into a comma separated sentence. (eg. sentence:"the bear ate an apple up the tree." --> "the,bear,ate,an,apple,up,the,tree") but I can't remove the words that I did not list out.
I have tried regexextract, but it only extract the first match. If there are multiple matches in a cell, it won't work.
I can't do a replace because I don't know what words I don't want as the sentence are very different. I only want a select few words. I also need it to be case sensitive. eg. if the word has a capital letter, I don't want it. If none of the words in the sentence matches what I want, I just need a blank, or a note that says "all good".
I only got up to this point
= textjoin(",",true,split(REGEXREPLACE( C9,"\[!@#$%^&\*().,。\]","")," "))

Welcome to Stack Overlow. Questions on this site should be about a specific problem unique to programming. You might ask another question focused on google-apps-script, but that question should be specific to stuff used in such platform,

@fancypotato Have you tried any of the given solutions? Did any work for you? If not we could try finding out why. If yes, please remember that you can also contribute to this community that helps you. As per site guidelines when an answer addresses your question, accept it and even upvote it so others can benefit as well.

Filter using Regex with Google Apps Script.
As per your comment, you wanted a custom formula, and I have explored ways to make it work. Here is an alternative approach you can use:
You can add multiple words as needed. Additionally, if a word is not present in the sentence, the script will leave the result blank.
Code:
    /**
 * Custom function to extract words from a list of sentences.
 * @param {Array} wordsRange - Range of words to extract.
 * @param {Array} sentencesRange - Range of sentences to process.
 * @return {Array} - An array of matching words for each sentence.
 * @customfunction
 */
function EXTRACT_WORDS(wordsRange, sentencesRange) {
  // Flatten and filter out empty values for the words range
  var words = wordsRange.flat().filter(String);
  var results = [];

  // Iterate through each sentence
  sentencesRange.forEach(function (row) {
    var sentence = row[0];
    if (sentence) {
      // Remove punctuation and split sentence into words
      var wordsInSentence = sentence.replace(/[!@#$%^&*().,?]/g, '').split(/\s+/);

      // Find matching words
      var matchingWords = wordsInSentence.filter(function (word) {
        return words.includes(word);
      });

      // Join matching words and add to results
      results.push([matchingWords.join(", ")]);
    } else {
      results.push([""]); // Leave blank if sentence is empty
    }
  });

  return results;
}

Here is a guide on how to do it:
1.) In Google Apps Script, click on Extensions,  Add the code above, and save it.
2.) Then, go back to the sheet and enter the formula: =EXTRACT_WORDS(wordsRange, sentencesRange).
Since this is a custom formula, there is no need for triggers.
Sample Output:

Reference/s:
Class SpreadsheetApp
JavaScript Array forEach()
if...else
Installable Triggers
Custom Functions in Google Sheets

wow i think this works the best thank you so much! how do I change it so that it works as a formula instead? the range of sentences to check is not fixed so its better as a custom formula that I can use in the cells i need

If this resolves your question, please click the check mark (✓) on the left to accept the answer and consider upvoting it. This helps others in the community who might have similar questions know that this solution works. If you cannot see the accept button, please let me know. For more information, you can refer to (https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

I've updated my answer for the alternative workaround based on your comment to utilize the custom function. Please check to see if it works for you.

Filter and Join Specific Words from Sentences Based on Keywords.
This formula will get the words that you put in $A$1:A$6 and then convert it into lowercase and remove punctuation for the comparison then split it into string then match the words in the "C3" and then I used TextJoin so that it joined both filtered and matched words to come up with your desire outcome.
Sample formula:
=TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE, FILTER(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(LOWER(C3), "[^\w\s]", ""), " "), MATCH(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(LOWER(C3), "[^\w\s]", ""), " "), LOWER($A$3:$A$6), 0)))

Sample Output


Note: Adjust the Range based on your needs.

References:
TextJoin
MATCH function
LOWER
FILTER function

omy gosh thank you so much! really appreciate it!

Extract Words from Sentence Based on List in Google Sheets
This formula checks if the words from the "Words I Want" column appear in the "String/Sentence" column, and if they do, it pastes those matching words into the "Desired Output" column as a comma-separated list. Adjust the range (A$2:A$4) if you want to add more words.
Please try and paste this code on the "Desired output" column to check if it's working on your end:
=TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE, FILTER(SPLIT(A$2:A$4, ", "), ARRAYFORMULA(LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(B2), "\b" & LOWER(TRIM(SPLIT(A$2:A$4, ", "))) & "\b")) > 0)))


References
SPLIT Function
REGEXEXTRACT Function
FILTER Function
LEN Function
TRIM Function
LOWER Function
ARRAYFORMULA Function
TEXTJOIN Function

If this resolves your issue, please click the accept button (checkmark icon) on the left and consider upvoting the answer. This helps others in the community with similar questions find solutions. If you don't see the accept button, feel free to let me know.

In cell G3 in the document you shared I entered yet another alternative:
=iferror(byrow(C3:C10, lambda(row, textjoin(", ", 1, filter(split(row, " "), regexmatch(split(row, " "), "(?i)"&textjoin("|", 1, A3:A10)))))))

See if that works?
